# How to get TextBoxFor to round, based on Entity Property Annotations, using MVC3 ASP.NET 4.5 and EF6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, entity-framework-6

I am using MVC3, ASP.NET 4.5, EF6, SQL Server 2008, C# , Razor.

I have created a POCO Entity class as the interface to my data using EF6.

I would like to have my decimal (20,4) properties round up after saving from a form. At present the first 4 decimals are taken irrespective of the 5th decimal ie no rounding

I get:

```
1.234567 -> 1.2345
```

I want:

```
1.234567 -> 1.2346
```

It would be ideal to specific this at the entity property level using annotations. I have played with DataFormatString which works well with "DisplayFor", but not for "TextBoxFor".

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Decimal1, new { style = "width:110px" })
```

My Entity property code is:

```
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = @"{0:G29}")]
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.RegularExpression(@"^[0-9]\d*(.\d+)?$", ErrorMessage = @"* Must be a number")]
    [System.ComponentModel.DisplayName("Decimal1 Value")]
    public virtual global::System.Nullable<decimal> Decimal1
    {
        get
        {
            return _Decimal1;
        }
        set
        {
            _Decimal1 = value;
        }
    }
```

How can I get @Html.TextBoxFor to pick up annotation rounding instructions for decimals like DisplayFor does?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no way to use `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:F4}")]`  attribute with [The Fixed-Point ("F") Format Specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=VS.90).aspx#FFormatString) that you need with `TextBoxFor` helper. But you can specify format using one of helper overloads like this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Decimal1, "{0:F4}" , new { @style = "width:110px" })
```

Comment: Thank you so much, back to my rescue again !! Out of interest, linked to my other question, is it possible to have a max 4 decimals, rounded to, but if less ie 1.25 then to just keep to the 2 provided?

Comment: Just tested the above, and it does not seem to work. It seems that there is no suitable parameter in TextBoxFor for "{0:F4}". I am using Razor1 from MVC3 if that makes a difference

Comment: Oops, you right this overloads has only mvc4. I think only solution is explisity specify value...

Comment: Here is my [old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27298546/1849444), but it's really not a good practice

Comment: Thanks for this..... A practical workaround. Another reason to get on and upgrade to MVC4/5 :)